# Why does an ideal gas not consist of identical molecules?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

since the mass , temperature , and number of particles are the same , shouldn't the molecules be the same so that the pressure of the gad is inversely proportional to the volume.

Comment: Since the temperature of what is the same as what?

Comment: Oh sorry for that.  I meant since the temperature and mass and number of particles of ideal gas is constant , then shouldn't decrease in volume cause pressure to rise but  only if the molecules are identical?

Comment: What would happen if the molecules weren't identical?  The pressure would still go up.  "ideal" has a specific meaning with gas laws, and it doesn't mean "identical molecules".  But I'm not exactly clear on what your question is yet.

Comment: Oh I just wanted to know why aren't the molecules identical won't it affect the mass of the ideal gas? Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You can edit your question at any time. Please take the comments into account and try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal gas is one that follows any of a number of linear relations such as $PV = k$ or $PV = nRT$.

Many gases near room temperature and atmospheric pressure are nearly ideal and show this relationship pretty closely.  All gasses deviate from the ideal as pressure increases and temperature decreases.  As an example, if you cool the gas so much that it condenses into a liquid or solid, then further volume decreases require significantly greater pressures than previously.

Making the molecules of the gas are identical or not has little to do with whether or not these ideal relationships hold.  You could combine two ideal gases and the resultant gas will usually be ideal as well.

If you imagine gas A in a container mostly bumping off the walls and gas B in a container mostly bumping all the walls, then putting them together doesn't necessarily cause them to interact much.  Each one is still bumping off the walls causing pressure.  So two non-identical molecules could be components of an ideal gas.  But changing their ratios would change the properties of that gas.

Some more information on your question would be good.  I think it can be made clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a confusion because there are two forms of the ideal gas equation.

In terms of moles the ideal gas equation is $PV = nRT$ where $R$ is the molar gas constant and is a constant independent of the gas or gases which are being considered.
In this equation there is no mention of the mass of the gas or the composition of the gas other than the number of moles of gas which is present.

Another form of the ideal gas equation is $PV = m R_{\text{specific}} T$ where $m$ is the mass of one type of gas $R_{\text{specific}}$ is the gas constant for unit mass of that gas.
This is the form of the gas equation which requires all the gas molecules to be identical.

The two gas equations are connected via the molar mass $M$ as $m = nM$ and $R_{\text{specific}} = \frac R M$